# Ruby on Rails: alias_method_chain, what exactly does it do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tried reading through various blog posts that attempt to explain alias_method_chain and the reasons to use it and not use it. In particular, I took heed to:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/4/26/new-in-rails-module-alias_method_chain

and

http://yehudakatz.com/2009/03/06/alias_method_chain-in-models/

I still do not see any practical use for alias_method_chain. Would anyone be able to explain a few things.

1 - is it still used at all?
2 - when would you use alias_method_chain and why?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

> 1 - is it still used at all?

Apparently yes, `alias_method_chain()` is [still used in Rails](http://github.com/search?type=Code&language=ruby&q=alias_method_chain+repo:rails/rails&repo=&langOverride=&x=23&y=7&start_value=1) (as of version 3.0.0).

> 2 - when would you use
>   alias_method_chain and why?

(***Note:*** the following is largely based on the discussion of `alias_method_chain()` in [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) by Paolo Perrotta, which is an excellent book that you should get your hands on.)

Let's start with a basic example:

```
class Klass
  def salute
    puts "Aloha!"
  end
end

Klass.new.salute # => Aloha!
```

Now suppose that we want to surround `Klass#salute()` with logging behavior. We can do that what Perrotta calls an *around alias*:

```
class Klass
  def salute_with_log
    puts "Calling method..."
    salute_without_log
    puts "...Method called"
  end

  alias_method :salute_without_log, :salute
  alias_method :salute, :salute_with_log
end

Klass.new.salute
# Prints the following:
# Calling method...
# Aloha!
# ...Method called
```

We defined a new method called `salute_with_log()` and aliased it to `salute()`. The code that used to call `salute()` still works, but it gets the new logging behavior as well. We also defined an alias to the original `salute()`, so we can still salute without logging:

```
Klass.new.salute_without_log # => Aloha!
```

So, `salute()` is now called `salute_without_log()`. If we want logging, we can call either `salute_with_log()` or `salute()`, which are aliases of the same method. Confused? Good!

According to Perrotta, this kind of around alias is very common in Rails:

> Look at another example of Rails
>   solving a problem its own way. A few
>   versions ago, the Rails code contained
>   many instances of the same idiom: an
>   *Around Alias* (155) was used to add a
>   feature to a method, and the old
>   version of the method was renamed to
>   something like
>   `method_without_feature()`. Apart from
>   the method names, which changed every
>   time, the code that did this was
>   always the same, duplicated all over
>   the place. In most languages, you
>   cannot avoid that kind of duplication.
>   In Ruby, you can sprinkle some
>   metaprogramming magic over your
>   pattern and extract it into its own
>   method... and thus was born
>   `alias_method_chain()`.

In other words, you provide the original method, `foo()`, and the enhanced method, `foo_with_feature()`, and you end up with three methods: `foo()`, `foo_with_feature()`, and `foo_without_feature()`. The first two include the feature, while the third doesn't. Instead of duplicating these aliases all around, [`alias_method_chain()` provided by ActiveSupport](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb#L23) does all the aliasing for you.

Comment: and small addition: so now we can just type ```alias_method_chain :foo, :feature``` and we will have 3 methods: ```foo```, ```foo_with_feature```, ```foo_without_feature``` which are properly aliased as *Yases Sulaiman* describe before

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."
Arthur C. Clarke

Answer (score 16):

`alias_method_chain` has been deprecated in Rails 5 in favour of `Module#prepend`.

Pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19434

Changelog: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b292b76c2dd0f04fb090d49b90716a0e6037b41a/guides/source/5_0_release_notes.md#deprecations-4

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's gone out of style with Rails 3 or not, but it is still actively used in versions before that.

You use it to inject some functionality before (or after) a method is called, without modifying any place that calls that method. See this example:

```
module SwitchableSmtp
  module InstanceMethods
    def deliver_with_switchable_smtp!(mail = @mail)
      unless logger.nil?
        logger.info  "Switching SMTP server to: #{custom_smtp.inspect}" 
      end
      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = custom_smtp unless custom_smtp.nil?
      deliver_without_switchable_smtp!(mail = @mail)
    end
  end
  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
    receiver.class_eval do
      alias_method_chain :deliver!, :switchable_smtp
    end
  end
end
```

That's an addition to ActionMailer to allow swapping out of the SMTP settings on each call to `deliver!`. By calling `alias_method_chain` you are able to define a method  `deliver_with_switchable_smtp!` in which you do your custom stuff, and call `deliver_without_switchable_smtp!` from there when you're done.

`alias_method_chain` aliases the old `deliver!` to your new custom method, so the rest of your app doesn't even know `deliver!` now does your custom stuff too.

Comment: Shouldn't `alias_method_chain :deliver!, :switchable_smtp` be `alias_method_chain :deliver!, :deliver_with_switchable_smtp!`?

Answer (score 3):

> is it used at all?

[Seems so](http://github.com/search?type=Code&language=ruby&q=alias_method_chain&repo=&langOverride=&x=24&y=26&start_value=1). It's a common practice among Rails developers

> when would you use alias_method_chain and why?

Despite the warnings, alias_method_chain is still the main strategy used when injecting functionality to an existing method, at least was in Rails 2.x and is followed by many people extending it. Yehuda ought to remove alias_method_chain from rails 3.0 to say from his posts and comments in Rails tickets. It is still used by many extensions that add custom behavior at certain points of the execution, such as loggers, error reporters, benchmarking, data injection, etc.

IMO, the best alternative is to include a module, thus you have decoration over delegation. (For example, follow example 4 in [this post](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/04/alternatives-for-redefining-methods.html)). That way you can alter the objects even individually if you'd like, without polluting the class' methods. The downside to this is that the method lookup chain increases for each module you inject, but this is what modules are for anyway.

Very interesting question, will keep a look on what other people think about it.