# Rails process_without methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I have a problem running [radiant mailer extension](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/mailer-extension) `SystemStackError in SiteController#show_page` on any page, which doesn't contain mailer functionality. 
I've found, that that there is a module that casus issues:

```
Module MailerProcess
  include RecaptchaMailer

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval {
      alias_method_chain :process, :mailer
      attr_accessor :last_mail
    }
  end

  def process_with_mailer(request, response)
    # If configured to do so, receive and process the mailer POST
    if Radiant::Config['mailer.post_to_page?'] && ... 
       # here process_mail from RecaptchaMailer called - works fine 
    end
    process_without_mailer(request, response)
  end
end
```

And here `process_without_mailer` is what completely confuses me - there is no such definition. THis method actually causes lots of "SHOW TABLES" in logs and finally the exception. 
This method i suspect is some more or less Rails part, bcause there are the same calls e.g. in `actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/filters.rb` (`process_without_filters`), `rails-4.0.0/guides/source/active_support_core_extensions.md` (`process_without_stringified_params`) - those methods also don't have any definitions.

So, there are two questions:

1. why `process_with_mailer` is called during **any** page load?
2. what's the magic behind `process_without_mailer`?

**UPD:**

ok, commenting out method `process_with_mailer` gives error during startup:

```
/home/sab/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:34:in `alias_method': undefined method `process_with_mailer' for class `Page' (NameError)
        from /home/sab/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:34:in `alias_method_chain'
        from /home/sab/_work/radiant-cms/vendor/extensions/mailer/lib/mailer_process.rb:6:in `block in included'
        from /home/sab/_work/radiant-cms/vendor/extensions/mailer/lib/mailer_process.rb:5:in `class_eval'
```

So, probably `alias_method_chain` causes calling method every page load, but mechanics is unclear to me. I've found some [ActiveSuppor](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain) doc.

**UPD2**
well i ended up with

1. Reading [Ruby on Rails: alias_method_chain, what exactly does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695839/ruby-on-rails-alias-method-chain-what-exactly-does-it-do)
2. commenting out `process_with_mailer` and `alias_method_chain`. on that configuration it sends emails, so that's acceptable. i still would like to know, what was author's general idea.

Comment: By looks of it, `process_with_mailer` is stuck in infinite recursive loop causing it to blow stack. can you commentout the recurive call & see it the error persists?

Comment: @Gaurish Commenting `process_without_mailer` causes:
`ERROR TypeError: can't convert Array into String
.../ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:61:in `block in service'
.../ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/response.rb:155:in `each'
.../ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/response.rb:155:in `each'
.../ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:16:in `method_missing'
.../ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:22:in `method_missing'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the article about `alias_method_chain` again, until you really get it. That is indeed what triggers `process_with_mailer` every time `process` is called.

By commenting out `process_with_mailer` and `alias_method_chain`, you essentially broke this code as it will never trigger again.
The reason that emails are now being sent, is because the mailer extension can be set up in two ways;

- if `Radiant::Config['mailer.post_to_page?']` is `true`, mailer forms will post to the current url. E.g. it will POST to domain.tld/contact, then Radiant finds the page at that path, and processes it. Thanks to the `alias_method_chain`, it will find out if the form has just been posted, and then do it's thing to actually send the mail.
- if `Radiant::Config['mailer.post_to_page?']` is not true (or not set), the contact form will POST to something like domain.tld/pages/:id/mail. That request is not handled by Radiant's SiteController, but by the MailController, which does not use process_with_mailer.
  The second is apparently your case, as you say that emails are properly sent now after commenting out the `alias_method_chain`.

Exactly what caused the SystemStackError is hard to say without a more complete error message, but: judging from something you pasted (activesupport-2.3.18), you are trying to use this extension with radiant 1.1.3, while it has not been updated in 4 years..
Do you actually use the recaptcha functionality? If not, I'd say drop this fork and use the 'normal' mailer extension that it is based on:
https://github.com/radiant/radiant-mailer-extension

Comment: great answer, thx! you've confirmed my suspicions that by commenting this part i'll loose ability to post with a better url than /pages/id/mail. 
you are correct i'm using recapthca fork actually, i've also tested with clean mailer extension, where the stack overflow persists as well. it wasn't updated for a year or two as well... still, i need captcha and i see it is in fact two or three lines of code that differ, so i could modify the 'normal' branch if it was in better state.

Comment: I use the mailer extension regularly and can assure you that it still works fine in the latest 1.x releases of Radiant. Perhaps you need to look for the cause elsewhere.. i.e. do you have a valid 'mailer' part etc.? Could you post the entire error you get?

Comment: unfortunately, have no time to reproduce it again, so i'll accept the answer since it really points tthe direction for investigation