# how to get how much time taken by RestClient to execute one method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest-client

I am using RestClient gem to execute API request.
I want to get how much time taken in execute that request.

```
responseObject = RestClient.post request_url,params[:request_body],:content_type => params[:content_type]
responseObject.code
```

now how can I get execution time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) for that purpose.

```
require "benchmark"

time = Benchmark.measure do
  responseObject = RestClient.post request_url,params[:request_body],:content_type => params[:content_type]     
end
```

Else in a primitive way:

```
beginning_time = Time.now
responseObject = RestClient.post request_url,params[:request_body],:content_type => params[:content_type]
end_time = Time.now
puts "Time elapsed #{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds"
```

Answer (score 2):

[alias_method_chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695839/ruby-on-rails-alias-method-chain-what-exactly-does-it-do) can be useful here.

Since `RestClient` is using a class called Request to execute all api requests (see source code [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L62)), you can add this snippet in an initializer to your rails project. Just add a `config.debug_rest_client_duration = true` in your environment config and it will work.

```
class RestClient::Request

  class << self
    def execute_with_log_duration(args, &block)
      started = Time.now
      res = execute_without_log_duration(args, &block)
      Rails.logger.info "api call duration is: " + (Time.now - started).to_s + " seconds"
      return res
    end
    alias_method_chain :execute, :log_duration if Rails.application.config.debug_rest_client_duration
  end

end
```