# Upgrade safe way to add controller action in redmine 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have a task to add custom functionality in projects module in redmine 4. I have tried to add in core app/project_controller.rb.can you let me help with correct way of adding new method in upgrade safe way.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to add new methods to Redmine is by creating plugins for it.

Plugin development is described on project's wiki:

https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial

Once you create a plugin, if it can be of benefit to open-source community, 
you can publish it on github and list in under Redmine's plugin directory:

https://www.redmine.org/plugins

Comment: Plugin has to be for new modules. I need to extend an existing module e.g Projects. I want to add a few new customization in it. Please consider that.

Comment: That's exactly what plugins are used for. There are methods which let you modify core behaviour and core visual user experience via Plugin hooks on views.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Aleksandar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800965/aleksandar-pavi%C4%87) answer. But I would add a few notes:

- I'm sure you need to start a plugin to do that
- Considering all the possibilities of extending Redmine, the [Tutorial](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial) is very incomplete
- I would take care before running the tutorial. I had some problems, it seems [outdated](https://www.redmine.org/issues/28340), but still useful reference
- You can find or publish plugins on [Redmine](https://www.redmine.org/plugins), but that page is a bit odd

First, I found Docs about Redmine which are very useful for a whole vision of the code. Unfortunately, Redmine has few code comments, a big mistake in my opinion.

- Redmine Ruby Doc https://www.rubydoc.info/github/edavis10/redmine/Project
- An [Entity Relation Diagram (PDF)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LLjzlUL3O32v_8gwxTavXM_nG-ojU4n5) I found somewhere and a [plugin to generate it](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_draw_erd) (but I can't comment on the plugin since I did not used, but I found it in my notes)

I think you'll need to use the following structre:

Your plugin's init.rb file should inject code into Redmine's Project or whatever model/class you need to override, like this:

```
require 'redmine'

# code injection
ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
  require 'my_file'   # but the file is actually lib/my_file.rb
  Project.send :include, MyFile
end

Redmine::Plugin.register :myproject do
name 'My New Project Plugin'
# ... the rest of your config
end
```

Once you require 'my_file' in *init.rb*, it is expected to be inside a lib directory *(lib/my_file.rb)*. So, your plugin's tree should be :

```
   -myproject
     -app
     -config
     -db
     -lib
       my_file.rb
     -test
```

'my_file' is a module, like this:

```
module MyFile
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # put your code here

  end
end
```

Your module can override methods in Project. If you *:include* a module with the same method in Project model, your code overwrite the core's one.

There is a [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19434) way to override methods that I recommend as a studding reference, though I need to fix that in a plugin of mine: [alias_method_chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695839/ddg#3697391).

Well, coding Ruby, Ruby on Rails and plugins for Redmine is something new for me and a bit of challenge,  so I suggest you consider this a good advice I never had!

Last, but not least, sign up for https://www.redmine.org and use the forums. Read all links in https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Developer_Guide .

Good work.