# where is the 3.1 version of the model association lines referenced in this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Ok...so, I have inherited an old Rails 2.3.14 app that I've recently upgraded to Rails 3.1 (yes I know 6.x is the most recent but baby steps first.)

I've discovered in the original code base what looks like some meta programing that has been done. Three classes have been overridden. Only the last...`class AssociationReflection` can be referenced in the Rails 3.1 Activerecord. The other two have been refactored into something else, somewhere else in Rails 3.1 Activerecord.

FYI: what is happening in this code is that alias_method is being used to allow for overrides of the original code with these modified copies.

...I have marked each line that was changed from the original with a `##ORIGINALY:` there are about 7 lines total, 6 of which I need to refactor.

`rails_fix.rb`

```
# NOTE: 
# This makes brittle code. the instant the original methods aliased here no
# longer exist on the rails 3.1 activeRecord side..this code will break..and 
# the app will break. Which is why the new programmer(me) has to fix it.
# This instantly coupled the code to a specific version of rails.
#
# NOTE: this is meta programming ... see SO post
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695839/ruby-on-rails-alias-method-chain-what-exactly-does-it-do

module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    module ClassMethods
      class JoinDependency
        class JoinAssociation
          def association_join_with_fix
            connection = reflection.active_record.connection
            join = case reflection.macro
                   when :has_and_belongs_to_many
                     " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                       table_alias_for(options[:join_table], aliased_join_table_name),
                       connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                       options[:foreign_key] || reflection.active_record.to_s.foreign_key,
                       connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                       reflection.active_record.primary_key] +
                       " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                         table_name_and_alias,
                         connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                         klass.primary_key,
                         connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                         options[:association_foreign_key] || klass.to_s.foreign_key
                       ]
                   when :has_many, :has_one
                     case
                     when reflection.options[:through]
                       through_conditions = through_reflection.options[:conditions] ? "AND #{interpolate_sql(sanitize_sql(through_reflection.options[:conditions]))}" : ''

                       jt_foreign_key = jt_as_extra = jt_source_extra = jt_sti_extra = nil
                       first_key = second_key = as_extra = nil

                       if through_reflection.options[:as] # has_many :through against a polymorphic join
                         jt_foreign_key = through_reflection.options[:as].to_s + '_id'
                         jt_as_extra = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                           connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                           connection.quote_column_name(through_reflection.options[:as].to_s + '_type'),
                           klass.quote_value(parent.active_record.base_class.name)
                         ]
                       else
                         jt_foreign_key = through_reflection.primary_key_name
                       end

                       case source_reflection.macro
                       when :has_many
                         if source_reflection.options[:as]
                           first_key = "#{source_reflection.options[:as]}_id"
                           second_key = options[:foreign_key] || primary_key
                           as_extra = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                             connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                             connection.quote_column_name("#{source_reflection.options[:as]}_type"),
                             klass.quote_value(source_reflection.active_record.base_class.name)
                           ]
                         else
                           first_key = source_reflection.association_foreign_key ##ORIGINALY: through_reflection.klass.base_class.to_s.foreign_key 
                           second_key = source_reflection.primary_key_name ##ORIGINALY: options[:foreign_key] || primary_key
                         end

                         unless through_reflection.klass.descends_from_active_record?
                           jt_sti_extra = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                             connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                             connection.quote_column_name(through_reflection.active_record.inheritance_column),
                             through_reflection.klass.quote_value(through_reflection.klass.sti_name)]
                         end
                       when :belongs_to
                         first_key = primary_key
                         if reflection.options[:source_type]
                           second_key = source_reflection.association_foreign_key
                           jt_source_extra = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                             connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                             connection.quote_column_name(reflection.source_reflection.options[:foreign_type]),
                             klass.quote_value(reflection.options[:source_type])
                           ]
                         else
                           second_key = source_reflection.primary_key_name
                         end
                       end

                       " #{join_type} %s ON (%s.%s = %s.%s%s%s%s) " % [
                         table_alias_for(through_reflection.klass.table_name, aliased_join_table_name),
                         connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name), ##ORIGINALY: connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                         connection.quote_column_name(parent.primary_key),
                         connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),##ORIGINALY: connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                         connection.quote_column_name(jt_foreign_key),
                         jt_as_extra, jt_source_extra, jt_sti_extra
                       ] +
                         " #{join_type} %s ON (%s.%s = %s.%s%s) " % [
                           table_name_and_alias,
                           connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                           connection.quote_column_name(first_key),
                           connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                           connection.quote_column_name(second_key),
                           as_extra
                         ]

                     when reflection.options[:as] && [:has_many, :has_one].include?(reflection.macro)
                       " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                         table_name_and_alias,
                         connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                         "#{reflection.options[:as]}_id",
                         connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                         parent.primary_key,
                         connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                         "#{reflection.options[:as]}_type",
                         klass.quote_value(parent.active_record.base_class.name)
                       ]
                     else
                       foreign_key = options[:foreign_key] || reflection.active_record.name.foreign_key
                       " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                         table_name_and_alias,
                         aliased_table_name,
                         foreign_key,
                         parent.aliased_table_name,
                         reflection.options[:primary_key] || parent.primary_key
                       ]
                     end
                   when :belongs_to
                     " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                       table_name_and_alias,
                       connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                       reflection.klass.primary_key, ##ORIGINALY: reflection.options[:primary_key] || reflection.klass.primary_key,
                       connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                       options[:foreign_key] || reflection.primary_key_name
                     ]
                   else
                     ""
                   end || ''
            join << %(AND %s) % [
              klass.send(:type_condition, aliased_table_name)] unless klass.descends_from_active_record?

            [through_reflection, reflection].each do |ref|
              join << "AND #{interpolate_sql(sanitize_sql(ref.options[:conditions], aliased_table_name))} " if ref && ref.options[:conditions]
            end

            join
          end

          alias_method_chain :association_join, :fix
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class HasManyThroughAssociation
      def construct_joins_with_fix(custom_joins = nil)
        polymorphic_join = nil
        if @reflection.source_reflection.macro == :belongs_to
          reflection_primary_key = @reflection.klass.primary_key
          source_primary_key = @reflection.source_reflection.primary_key_name
          if @reflection.options[:source_type]
            polymorphic_join = "AND %s.%s = %s" % [
              @reflection.through_reflection.quoted_table_name, "#{@reflection.source_reflection.options[:foreign_type]}",
              @owner.class.quote_value(@reflection.options[:source_type])
            ]
          end
        else
          reflection_primary_key = @reflection.source_reflection.primary_key_name
          source_primary_key = @reflection.source_reflection.association_foreign_key ##ORIGINALY: @reflection.through_reflection.klass.primary_key
          if @reflection.source_reflection.options[:as]
            polymorphic_join = "AND %s.%s = %s" % [
              @reflection.quoted_table_name, "#{@reflection.source_reflection.options[:as]}_type",
              @owner.class.quote_value(@reflection.through_reflection.klass.name)
            ]
          end
        end

        "INNER JOIN %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s %s #{@reflection.options[:joins]} #{custom_joins}" % [
          @reflection.through_reflection.quoted_table_name,
          @reflection.quoted_table_name, reflection_primary_key,
          @reflection.through_reflection.quoted_table_name, source_primary_key,
          polymorphic_join
        ]
      end

      alias_method_chain :construct_joins, :fix
    end
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  module Reflection
    class AssociationReflection
      def association_foreign_key_with_fix
        @association_foreign_key ||= @options[:primary_key] || class_name.foreign_key ##ORIGINALY: @association_foreign_key ||= @options[:association_foreign_key] || class_name.foreign_key
      end

      alias_method_chain :association_foreign_key, :fix
    end
  end
end
```

NOTE: this is meta programming ... see SO post
[Ruby on Rails: alias_method_chain, what exactly does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695839/ruby-on-rails-alias-method-chain-what-exactly-does-it-do)

So the Question is: What has...

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class HasManyThroughAssociation
      def construct_joins
```

...and...

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    module ClassMethods
      class JoinDependency
        class JoinAssociation
          def association_join
```

...been refactored to and what are the equivalents of the 6 lines Marked "#ORIGINALY:" ?

As I figure I might have to build another version of `rails_fix.rb` with the Rails 3.1 versions of the ActiveRecord Association methods. But I don't know what/where that current code is.

I hope this question made sense. Thank you for your time.

Comment: First I'd ask if these patches are even needed in more modern versions of ActiveRecord (even 3.1 qualifies as modern compared to 2). Look for official/supported ways to do what your patches are trying to do (and of course, have tests in place to make sure).

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah..I hear you. The test suit is broken (of course). On "looking for official/supported ways..." That's the thing. I'm not entirely sure what they where attempting to do here. It looks like the original dev was trying to swap the table values in the joins...I think....not sure